# Setting up Web API for Public Access in a Docker Container

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core

I'm trying to set up my .NET API to run in a Docker container and be accessible via my browser. I'm trying to get it working when deployed to my server.

The repo (on the dev branch specifically) is here: https://github.com/rarDevelopment/rardk-web-dotnet/tree/dev

I've set up port mapping in the `docker run` step, but trying to reach my server's IP gets no response. I can ping the IP and SSH into the server no problem, but entering the IP into my browser (including specifying `:8080`) doesn't get any response ("too long to respond").

Here's the run command I'm using:

```
docker run -d --name=${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }} -p 8080:80 --log-driver json-file --log-opt max-size=10m --log-opt max-file=3 --restart=unless-stopped ${{ env.CURRENT_ID }}:latest
```

I'm certain I'm missing some vital setup, but I can't find where my specific setup is wrong to figure out where to continue.

Comment: Please add your `docker run` command, including port mappings, to your question. And a description of how you try to access your API. You should also limit yourself to one question per post.

Comment: Oops, I'd copied the docker run command to add it and then totally forgot. Updated my question!

Comment: Starting with .NET 8, ASP.NET containers listen on port 8080 by default, so you need to use `-p 8080:8080`. If you only had one question in your post, I could write an answer, but now I can't :)

Comment: I've updated the post to remove the other question, now it focuses just on the Docker aspect